# webRTC multi-peer connection (3 clients and above)

Tags: connection, webrtc, multipeer-connectivity, simplewebrtc

i want to use a simple WebRTC for my clients like this one (https://appr.tc/).
The problem with the above link is that it can only take up to 2 users(A and B). Do you know if there are any others FREE programms that take clients A,B,C and D?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple example of multi-peer connection audio/video. With a [DEMO](https://dirvann-webrtc-video.herokuapp.com/). It uses simple-peer as wrapper of RTCPeerconnection.

https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this concept is that the peer connections use too much computing power.
Isn't there a possibility to get a peer connection to multiply peers.

Ps. I try to point out, there are a dict within a lot of peer connections.