# capture video conference between 1:1 user and broadcast to an rtmp url

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, socket.io, webrtc

I am currently working on nodejs and socket app that is currently doing 1:1 video conference that is using webrtc. Videos are two separate element in the html and i would like to merge them together so that i can broadcast to rtmp url for public view (2:many). Is this possible

For webrtc, i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvlyzDZDEq4, and for broadcasting i am using ffmpeg which current does 1 video stream.

Please confirm if this is doable

**Update**

I was able to merge the video using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/video-stream-merger

And now the final issue

i am receiving merger.result which is merged stream and I tried to create a mediaRecorder object. Callback method for MediaRecorder ondataavailable is called only once but not every 250ms which i need to broadcast to youtube. How can i do this?

```
var merger = new VideoStreamMerger(v_opts);
...
...
merger.start()
myMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(merger.result);
myMediaRecorder.start(250);
myMediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
    console.log("DataAvailable")
    //socket.emit("binarystream", e.data);
    state = "start";
    //chunks.push(e.data);
}
```

Comment: Hello, maybe you should look at in [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) and [Software Recommandations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @asif-alamgir, Have you found a solution for your problem? I have similar issue as well and it would be great if you share with us.

Comment: No unfortunately, had to use a third party service @JustShadow

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for *many peers*. This is possible - please see the below links for reference.

- WebRTC: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/
- StackOverflow reference: [webRTC multi-peer connection (3 clients and above)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740054/webrtc-multi-peer-connection-3-clients-and-above)
- GitHub reference: https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer
- https://deepstream.io/tutorials/webrtc/webrtc-full-mesh/

Comment: @Asif-Alamgir do you think this answer covers what you're asking for?

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt. Webrtc solution is already in there, but i am trying to combine the video so that i can send to youtube rtmp